# Lightning Events in Lightning Page Context

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning, community-builder

So I have a community builder page with 2 custom lightning components I've dropped into different sections - how do I make them communicate via events?

[image]

I know that when you have a component inside another component, I can use component events to trigger actions in the component hierarchy.  And when I have 2 components within the same Lightning App, I can use APPLICATION events to trigger actions across any component in the App.

How does it work if I have components on a Lightning page?  They are not nested inside the same App (we're using Community Builder), and the components aren't nested within the same hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the same page, in a community you'd be within the same domain, making your components part of the same application event level access, even if you didn't define them as part of the same application. You could of course define [ExternalEvent Handlers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.lightning.meta/lightning/events_external.htm) for the "window" but that shouldn't be necessary. See the [Advanced Events Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.lightning.meta/lightning/events_demo.htm) for more on this topic.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that link after posting the question, and realized that they weren't using a lightning app in the example (all the other examples show components within an app).  I'll go give it a try :)

Comment: +1 @crmprogdev Application events should just work here and worth trying it .

Comment: Testing this and it doesn't seem to be working.  I get the event to fire just fine, however the component sitting next to it on the page isn't firing the action function declared in the aura:handler.

Comment: Only thing I can think of at this point is to wrap them both in a parent component, and then use an event extension to use in the sibling component.

Comment: ok, so this was not working for 1/2 an hour, then I simply added a console.log() statement after may "evt.fire()" call.... and now it works.  I've no idea why this happened - and I don't think this is the first time I've seen this behavior in Lightning components...  :|

Comment: Am pleased to hear you got it sorted Jason. Am confident that your question will be helpful to many others as people continue to begin using lightning components in Communities.

Comment: @JasonBenkert, You might have had a caching issue, I always make sure I hit ctrl+f5 to make sure my cache is cleared and I get the most recent version of my component.